# JavaFX not storing string values in ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I cannot get my string values to print into the GUI ComboBox I have built. Essentially, every time I assign the value of my `cbGame`ComboBox into the JavaFX program, it gives me an illegal argument exception when I try to launch the GUI. The full code is on my GitHub: https://github.com/jparr721/Blue-Box2
the code that I need help with is as follows.

Controller class:

```
public class RentGameDialogController extends RentalStoreGUIController implements Initializable{

@FXML private TextField nameField, rentedOn, dueBack;
String name;
Date dateRentedOn, dateDue;
GregorianCalendar rented, due;
@FXML private ObservableList<String> cbGameOptions;
@FXML private ComboBox<String> cbGame;
@FXML ComboBox<PlayerType> cbConsole;
@FXML Button cancel, addToCart;
int counter = 0;
private Stage currentStage;


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    cbGameOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    cbGameOptions.add("The Witcher 3");
    cbGameOptions.add("Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare");
    cbGameOptions.add("Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare");
    cbGameOptions.add("The Elder Scrolls IV: Skyrim");

    cbGame.setItems(cbGameOptions);

}

public void getName(){
    name = nameField.getText();

    try {

        String[] firstLast = name.split(" ");
        String firstName = firstLast[0];
        String lastName = firstLast[1];

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getRentedOn() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    dateRentedOn = format.parse(rentedOn.getText());
    rented.setTime(dateRentedOn);
}

public void getDueBack() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    dateDue = format.parse(dueBack.getText());
    due.setTime(dateDue);
}


@FXML
public void handleCancelButtonAction (ActionEvent event) {
    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}

@FXML
public void addToCartButton (ActionEvent event) {

    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}}
```

Here is the JavaFX application where I assign cbGame to the ComboBox.
[image: JavaFX GUI]

Comment: Please post the FXML in your actual question. Posting a question with insufficient detail to answer it simple encourages people to guess at the answer.

Comment: “it gives me an illegal argument exception” Edit your question and include the full stack trace of that IllegalArgumentException.  It tells us (and you) exactly which line of code caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know the problem, i open your code and saw that you are not using comboBox in your fxml so I change it with combo box, you are using SplitMenuButton.

[image]

```
 @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         cbGameOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            cbGameOptions.add("The Witcher 3");
            cbGameOptions.add("Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare");
            cbGameOptions.add("Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare");
            cbGameOptions.add("The Elder Scrolls IV: Skyrim");

            cbGame.getItems().addAll(cbGameOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay firstly remove where you have written `cbGame.setItems(cbGameOptions);`

You must instead

```
cbGame.getItems().addAll(cbGameOptions);
```

Comment: Either one of those should work. That is not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a `@FXML` annotation for an ObservableList. The `@FXML` tag enables an FXMLLoader to inject values defined in an FXML but your observableList doesn't need to be set by the FXMLLoader

So

```
@FXML private ObservableList<String> cbGameOptions;
```

should be

```
private ObservableList<String> cbGameOptions;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's true that `@FXML` doesn't make sense here, but why would it actually stop it working?